# Python visualization of a function with 2 variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I try to visualize a simple function with 2 variables. When the function is `x**2 + y**2` the minima on the plot locates at (0, 0) as expected, but when the function is `(x + 1)**2 + (y + 1)**2` the minima locates at (-1, 1). x coordinate is correct, but y coordinate is not (should be (-1, -1)). Could someone explain why when I add to x any value, x coordinate of the minima is always correct, but when I add any number to y, then y coordinate of the minima always locates in incorrect location? How can I fix it?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function
def circle(x, y):
    return (x + 1)**2+(y + 1)**2


# Grid for plotting
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)


# 2D
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(circle(X, Y), extent = [-3, 3, -3, 3], cmap=plt.cm.jet)
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Something seems wrong with the formatting. Could you fix it?

Comment: Formatting is done

Answer (score 1):

According to the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/pcolor_demo.html) you have to set `origin` to "lower":

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function
def circle(x, y):
    return (x + 1) ** 2 + (y + 1) ** 2

# Grid for plotting
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = circle(X, Y)

plt.imshow(Z, cmap = "jet", extent=[-3, 3, -3, 3],  origin = "lower")
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

If origin is not specified, [`imshow` defaults to the standard value](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html), which is in this case the upper left corner. Hence only the y values are affected.

Alternatively, you could also use [`pcolor`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pcolor.html):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the function
def circle(x, y):
    return (x + 1) ** 2 + (y + 1) ** 2

# Grid for plotting
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101)
y = np.linspace(-3, 3, num = 101)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)

Z = circle(X, Y)

plt.pcolor(X, Y, Z, cmap = "jet")
plt.axis([-3, 3, -3, 3])
plt.colorbar()

plt.show()
```